# Testing Android Project in a Docker Environment: local.properties no such file

Tags: java, android, docker, gradle

I'm using the tool Buddy.works to test an android application.

It first creates a docker image from this docker file: https://hub.docker.com/r/dwillmc/android-27-alpha-ndk/~/dockerfile/

Then I attempt to run `./gradlew test` and get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/buddy/camerakit-android/camerakit/build.gradle' line: 33
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':camerakit'.
> /buddy/camerakit-android/local.properties (No such file or directory)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s
```

Line 33 is inside the following function

```
ext.getBintrayUser = { ->
    if (System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')) {
        return System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    }

    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream()) //line 33
    return properties.getProperty('bintray.user')
}
```

The project builds without error on my local machine.

I'm fairly ignorant about the gradle build process, so any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if other information would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [this issue](https://github.com/workarounds/typography/issues/4) the `local.properties` file hasn't been created

> since Android Studio automatically generates local.properties

and therefore it cannot be opened by `rootProject.file`.  Either you create this file yourself or check it's existence before calling `properties.load`.

```
if (rootProject.file('local.properties').exists())
```